# Find commits on GitHub by author who doesn't have a GitHub account

Tags: git, github

Suppose I would like to find commits by a certain contributor in the Linux Kernel.
https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commits/master

For example, there is [a recent commit](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commit/39d0d3bdf7bab3021a31e501172ac0f18947f9b3) authored by Anna Schumaker (I took the most recent commit in the current history that is not authored by a github account).

Some other SO questions on the topic suggest using `https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commits/master?author=AUTHOR` to find more commits by the same author.

However:

- https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commits/master?author=torvalds gives me quite a large list of commits
- https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commits/master?author=Anna+Schumaker gives empty results. I also tried, out of curiosity, to search for the user who signed-off this commit: https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commits/master?author=Trond+Myklebust - also zero results. I also tried putting in the full name and email rather than just name.

Is this a missing feature in Github? Am I doing it wrong?

P.S. I am aware of ways to accomplish this using git command-line tools. I am specifically looking for ways to do this with Github, because I'd like to be able to produce a link to the search so someone else can look at the results on the web.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can pass in the `author` parameter the username or the email address. As you noticed, using `?author=torvalds` gives you the commits.

Since Anna doesn't have a GitHub account, you can use her email. But how to find her email knowing the commit?

Having the [commit url](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commit/39d0d3bdf7bab3021a31e501172ac0f18947f9b3) (which looks like this: `https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commit/39d0d3bdf7bab3021a31e501172ac0f18947f9b3`), append the `.patch` snippet at the end. You should get something like [this](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commit/39d0d3bdf7bab3021a31e501172ac0f18947f9b3.patch):

> `https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commit/39d0d3bdf7bab3021a31e501172ac0f18947f9b3.patch`

The response looks like this:

```
From 39d0d3bdf7bab3021a31e501172ac0f18947f9b3 Mon Sep 17 00:00:00 2001
From: Anna Schumaker <Anna.Schumaker@netapp.com>
Date: Mon, 5 Oct 2015 16:43:26 -0400
Subject: [PATCH] NFS: Fix a tracepoint NULL-pointer dereference

Running xfstest generic/013 with the tracepoint nfs:nfs4_open_file
enabled produces a NULL-pointer dereference when calculating fileid and
filehandle of the opened file.  Fix this by checking if state is NULL
before trying to use the inode pointer.

Reported-by: Olga Kornievskaia <aglo@umich.edu>
Signed-off-by: Anna Schumaker <Anna.Schumaker@Netapp.com>
Signed-off-by: Trond Myklebust <trond.myklebust@primarydata.com>
---
 fs/nfs/nfs4trace.h | 2 +-
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+), 1 deletion(-)

diff --git a/fs/nfs/nfs4trace.h b/fs/nfs/nfs4trace.h
index 28df12e..671cf68 100644
--- a/fs/nfs/nfs4trace.h
+++ b/fs/nfs/nfs4trace.h
@@ -409,7 +409,7 @@ DECLARE_EVENT_CLASS(nfs4_open_event,
            __entry->flags = flags;
            __entry->fmode = (__force unsigned int)ctx->mode;
            __entry->dev = ctx->dentry->d_sb->s_dev;
-           if (!IS_ERR(state))
+           if (!IS_ERR_OR_NULL(state))
                inode = state->inode;
            if (inode != NULL) {
                __entry->fileid = NFS_FILEID(inode);
```

You see in the second line that you have the author name and email address. Now, knowing the email address, you can [fetch person's commits in that repository](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commits?author=Anna.Schumaker@netapp.com):

```
https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commits?author=Anna.Schumaker@netapp.com
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, time and again, the best way to solve a problem is to publicly proclaim that I don't know how to solve it... Immediately after posting the question I realized I haven't tried searching for just the email:

https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commits/master?author=Anna.Schumaker@Netapp.com

gives the expected results.

Comment: I added a more detailed answer. Maybe it will be useful for posterity. :)